# Form in masterpage shows as white div ONLY in IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

We have a masterpage for our website made in asp.net c# visual studio 2010.
It shows perfect in safari, opera, chrome, firefox and IE10, but IE9 shows a big white block between the menu en the content.

When we push F12 and inspect the element it highlights the form that has everything wrapped inside it (this was done so that more that on other pages the notation form runat=server is not necessary anymore, since more than one of those forms running at server gives an error).

This is the link to the website: http://iwtsw.ehb.be/~iris.vdz/Index.aspx

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MainLayout.master.cs" Inherits="MainLayout" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Website Euroquip</title>
    <link href="~/Styles/MainLayout.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Styles/brlnsr.ttf" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/flavicons/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="images/flavicons/animated_favicon1.gif">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>

        function setBodyContentMinHeight() {
            var height = $("#leftContent").height();
            $('#bodyContent').css('min-height', (height-25) + "px");
        }

        $(function () {
            setBodyContentMinHeight();
            var $sidebar = $("#leftContent"),
            $window = $(window),
            offset = $sidebar.offset(),
            topPadding = 15;

            $window.scroll(function () {

                if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                }
            });


        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="HeaderContent" class="centeredContent">
            <a href="Index.aspx" id="logoDiv">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo euroquip" style="height: 146px" />
             </a>
            <div id="menuDiv">
                <asp:Menu ID="headMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"
                    StaticSubMenuIndent="16px" CssClass="headMenu" Font-Names="brlnsr" 
                    meta:resourcekey="headMenuResource1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0">
                    <LevelMenuItemStyles>
                    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="menu"/>
                    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="menu"/>
                    </LevelMenuItemStyles>
                </asp:Menu>
                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />


            </div>

            <div id="languagesDiv"  class="styled-select shadow">
                        <form id="ddlLanguage" action="" method="post">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="languages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            CssClass="ddlLanguages" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="languages_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                            meta:resourcekey="languagesResource1">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="NL" Value="nl" 
                                 />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="EN" Value="en"  />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="FR" Value="fr"  />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </form>
                    </div>

        </div>

        <div id="bodyContent" class="centeredContent">
            <div id="leftContent">
                <div id="secondaryMenuDiv"  class="roundedFrame shadow blackFrame">
                    <div id="secondaryMenuDivHeader" runat="server">
                        <asp:Localize ID="Localize1" runat="server" 
                            meta:resourcekey="Localize1Resource1" Text="Wij bieden aan:"></asp:Localize></div>
                              <asp:Panel ID="MenuPanel" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Panel1Resource1">
                              </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Div1" class="roundedFrame shadow blackFrame">
                    Promoties
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rightContent">
               <!-- <div id="contentDiv" class="roundedFrame shadow" > -->
               <div id="contentDiv">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentHolder" runat="server" >
                        Hier komt de content
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="clearer"></div>

       </div>


       <div id="footerContent">
            <div id="footerContentCenter" class="centeredContent">
                <div id="sitemapContact" class="sitemapColumn">
                    <h1><a href="Contact.aspx"><asp:Localize ID="contact" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="contactResource1" 
                            Text="CONTACT"></asp:Localize></a></h1>
                    <div class="ColumnContent">
                    <a href="https://maps.google.be/maps?q=Industriestraat+16+3930+Hamont-Achel&hnear=Industriestraat+16,+3930+Hamont-Achel,+Limburg,+Vlaams+Gewest&gl=be&t=h&z=16&iwloc=A" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/icons/world.png"/><p>Industriestraat 16 </br> 
                        3930 Hamont-Achel </p>
                    </a>
                    <img src="images/icons/phone.png" /><p>011 80 75 30 (t)</br>
                        011 64 61 82 (f) </p>
                    <a href="mailto:info@euroquip.be"><img src="images/icons/email.png" /><p>info@euroquip.be</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sitemapNieuwsbrief" class="sitemapColumn">
                    <a href="#nieuwsbriefEmail" onclick="document.getElementById('nieuwsbriefEmail').focus();"><h1><asp:Localize ID="nieuwsbrief" runat="server" 
                            meta:resourcekey="nieuwsbriefResource1" Text="NIEUWSBRIEF"></asp:Localize></h1></a>
                    <div id="toTo"></div>
                    <div class="ColumnContent">
                    <p>
                        <form id="nieuwsbrief" action="" method="post">
                            <input id="nieuwsbriefEmail" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="" />
                            <input id="nieuwsbriefEmailVerzenden" type="submit" value="OK"/>
                        </form>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <img src="images/icons/feed.png" /> RSS FEED
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sitemapSiteMap" class="sitemapColumn">
                    <a href="Sitemap.aspx"><h1>SITEMAP</h1></a>
                     <div class="ColumnContent">
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sitemapWebshop" class="sitemapColumn">
                    <a href="Shop.aspx"><h1>WEBSHOP</h1></a>
                    <div class="ColumnContent">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="copyright">
                Copyright &copy;2013 Euroquip
                </br>
                Design by Team Kinik.
                </div>
              </div>  
        </div>


     </div>

      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Would anyone know what we are doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried removing  the css rule that sets body height to 100% from your MainLayout.css?

Comment: Pleas do not take this the wrong way but have you cleared your browser cache as well, I am speaking from experience :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `height:100%` on line 29 in MainLayout.css.

IE 9 has height quirks that other browsers properly handle.

Comment: thanxxx! this was driving us crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you disable height:100% using Internet explorer developer tools (CSS tab) then the page layout works as expected.

Therefore you should remove the css rule that sets body height to 100% from your MainLayout.css.

Veel success ermee!

Comment: It was form height that did the trick, not body height, but it was close ;)